# Can someone point me towards research works relevant to Importance or Weighting Datapoints like SAW(Stepwise adaptation of weights) technique?

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, weighted-sampling, weighted-data, genetic-algorithms

I am working on Fitness case importance for Symbolic Regression and found a Paper  "[Step-wise Adaptation of Weights for Symbolic Regression with Genetic Programming](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Ewbl/biblio/cache/cache/.hidden_13-jun_2105304592/http___www.vanhemert.co.uk_publications_bnaic00.Stepwise_Adaptation_of_Weights_for_Symbolic_Regression_with_Genetic_Programming.pdf)" which talks about weights of fitness cases  to give importance to points which are not evolved to boost performance and also get GP out of local optima.

This publication is too old and i am looking for new work which talk about fitness cases importance. But i am not able to find any such publication. Instead i find Publications related to sampling on Random selection in different ways.

So, Can someone point me towards research works relevant to Importance or Weighting Datapoints like SAW(Stepwise adaptation of weights) technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your question, we first study what is a weighted sampling, which is a natural concern arise from bootstrapping technique when the sampling pool is not infinite (unlike some classical asymptotics) but finite. Weighted sampling is basically a variance reduction technique for bootstrap estimators.
An crucial special case of weighted sampling is the importance sampling, which is closely related to the bootstrap:

> Johns, M. Vernon. "Importance sampling for bootstrap confidence
> intervals." Journal of the American Statistical Association 83.403
> (1988): 709-714.

A practical realization of importance sampler is in:

> Martino, Luca, et al. "An adaptive population importance sampler:
> Learning from uncertainty." IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing
> 63.16 (2015): 4422-4437.

For Bayesian weighted sampling,

> Lo, Albert Y. "A Bayesian method for weighted sampling." The Annals of
> Statistics (1993): 2138-2148.

Back to your question of adaptive weights, it is more or less a penalized likelihood method(based on the fitness function) of choosing weights in a weighted sampling procedure, which is proposed earlier in:

> Eggermont, Jeroen, A. E. Eiben, and Jano I. van Hemert. "Adapting the
> fitness function in GP for data mining." European Conference on
> Genetic Programming. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 1999.